# how to read send(sock_fd, line, size, 0);?

Tags: c, sockets

How to read `send(sock_fd, line, size, 0);`

I have a program like this,

`if (send(new_socket,sendToEMVSS,EMVSSSendBufferLength,0)!=EMVSSSendBufferLength)`

I try to run the program but the result is always `!=EMVSSSendBufferLength`

Comment: The `send` function returns `-1` on error. You need to check for that.

Comment: For better understanding whats going on you can divide the code. Hold the returned value in `retval` an integer, and then print the value and check whats going on.

Comment: If no error occurs, `send` returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the `size` parameter.

Comment: Is the socket blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: how to know if the socket blocking or non-blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to keep the return value.

- If it is -1, than you'll find detailed error information in `errno`.
- If it is positive, but less than `EMVSSSendBufferLength` it means only that many bytes were send and you'll have to send the rest with separate call. That separate call will likely block (or fail with `errno == EAGAIN` if it is non-blocking), because the reason not to send everything is that the transmit window is full.

Also is the packet really fixed size? Are you not passing the size of buffer instead of size of the actual message by mistake?

Comment: @ZuL: `errno` is simply a macro behaving like integer variable, possible values are listed in the documentation of [`send`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html). And remember that `errno` is set to the error code on error, but not cleared on success, so you need to check whether send returned -1 first.

Comment: Tq. Hi, i checked.. its return -1